# I need to create an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops, infinity

For my purpose I need to create loop where one variable is looping in this way: 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1...

It's look simple but more than hour I wonder how to do it.
My purpose is moving the star in this way

```
*....
.*...
..*..
...*.
....*
...*.
..*..
.*...
*....
*....
.*...
..*..
...*.
....*
```

Comment: that is just going to crash your browser :-(

Comment: Do you need to print? what is the stopping point? what is the purpose?

Comment: Do you want `0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,1...` (according to your text) or `0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,0,1...` (according to the ascii-art)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to generate the number pattern that you require. However, you wont be able to run it infinitely since it will crash the browser.

If you want to test, I have added instructions for making the loop infinite.

For you requirement, a larger value for `rep` variable will be enough.

```js
let min = 0; // Start/min value
let max = 4; // Max value
let dir = 1; // Count direction (+1/-1)

let counter = min; // Your counter variable

let rep = 24; // Remove this line and change condition inside while to true for infinite loop

do {
  console.log(counter);

  dir = counter===max?-1:counter===min?1:dir;
  counter+=dir;
} while (rep-->0); // Change this expression to true for infinite loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Write that loop as a generator (`function *... yield`) and then consume it when you need it (`for...of`). Of course, the consuming code must provide some termination condition.

```js
function* bounce(min, max) {
  while (1) {
    for (let i = min; i < max; i++)
      yield i;
    for (let i = max; i > min; i--)
      yield i;
  }
}

STEPS = 10

for(let x of bounce(0, 4)) {
  console.log(x)
  if (--STEPS === 0) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout or setInterval for doing that:

```js
let number = 0;
let increment = 1;
const from = 0;
const to = 4;

const starDiv = document.getElementById("star");

function printStar(number) {
  const text = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(
    i => (i === number) ? '*' : '-'
  ).join('');
  starDiv.innerText = text;
}

function loop() {
  printStar(number);
  number += increment;

  if (number == to) {
    increment = -1;
  } else if (number == from) {
    increment = 1;
  }
}

const time = 10; // 10 millisecond between step
setInterval(loop, time);
```

```html
<div id="star">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple counter and then use `modulo 8` to get iterations.

```
let x = (i += direction) % 8;
let y = x > 4 ? 8 - x : x;
```

This example even prints the ascii art ;)

```js
let i = -1;
let direction = +1;
const out = [
  "*....",
  ".*...",
  "..*..",
  "...*.",
  "....*",
  "...*.",
  "..*..",
  ".*...",
  "*....",
];
setInterval(function() {
  let x = (i += direction) % 8;
  let y = x > 4 ? 8 - x : x;
  window.document.write(y + " " + out[x] + "<br>");
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(min,max,max_loops)
{
    for(var loop = 1; loop <= max_loops; loop++, [min,max] = [-max,-min])
    {
        for(num = min; num < max + (loop == max_loops); num++)
        {
            console.log(".".repeat(Math.abs(num)) + "*" +  ".".repeat(Math.max(Math.abs(max),Math.abs(min)) - Math.abs(num)))
        }
    }
})(0,4,3)
```

But since you need an infinite loop, using generator should be more suitable.